# install portaudio with ./configure in unix systems

Tags: installation, portaudio

Basic unix installation ignorance, I suppose.  I'm trying to install/build Port Audio on macOS 10.11 in a terminal session.  I downloaded Port Audio into a developer directory (using both the tarball and the git versions) and tried to follow the basic build instructions given on the website.  I dragged the directory over to the terminal window to set it up.  Then tried the "./configure && make".  Using the command on the directory won't work.  I can't find a file in there that I can use these commands on.  What basic concept am I missing?

Thanks.

Okay, I figured out that I was changing the directory incorrectly using cd.  Don't know why, but I had to change one directory at a time or bash would kick me back to the beginning directory.  When I finally got to the portaudio directory, "./configure && make" worked just as advertised.  Solved.

Comment: Note that you can also install PortAudio with [brew](http://brew.sh): `brew install portaudio`